# How to create TextField with Clear button using TextEditingController?

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout

I tried to create a TextField with clear button, but when i enter some value there's no clear button show up as I wanted to. Seems like it cant detect the changes to the `_firstNameController.text`. How can I solve this issue?

[image]

```
class TextFieldWithClearBtn extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _TextFieldWithClearBtnState createState() => _TextFieldWithClearBtnState();
}

class _TextFieldWithClearBtnState extends State<TextFieldWithClearBtn> {
  final TextEditingController _firstNameController = TextEditingController();

  @override
  void dispose {
    super.dispose();
    _firstNameController.dispose();
  }
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      child: TextFormField(
        controller: _firstNameController,
        decoration: InputDecoration(
          labelText: "First name",
          suffixIcon: _firstNameController.text.isNotEmpty
            ? GestureDetector(
              onTap: () {
                WidgetsBinding.instance.addPostFrameCallback((_) => _firstNameController.clear());
              },
              child: Icon(Icons.clear, color: Colors.black38),
            )
            : null
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Instead of `suffixIcon`, you `suffix`. This way the `clear` button will not be visible if `textformfield` is not in focus and will display the `icon` when you tap on the field. Also, when you will tap on the `clear` icon after typing something, it'll clear the field. Working sample code below:

```
TextFormField(
      controller: _firstNameController,
                      textAlign: TextAlign.left,
                      cursorColor: Colors.white,
                      onChanged: (value) {

                      },
                      style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white),
                      decoration: InputDecoration(    
                        labelText: 'First Name',
                        suffix: GestureDetector(
                        onTap: () {
                          _firstNameController.clear();
                        },
                          child: Icon(Icons.clear)
                        )
                      ),
                    ),
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you very much Darshan. This is very helpful! I've been figuring this out for hours!